# Vue - Standard practice when accessing slots

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is the following an accepted standard practice when attempting to access slots?

```
    const slotElement = this.$slots['slot-name'][0].elm;
    const value = this.getSomething(slotElement);
```

Comment: Try not to interact directly with the DOM element, as it's an anti-pattern in Vue. What do you need from the slot that you need to access that underlaying element?

Comment: No, unfortunately. That's not a good idea. The slot may be filled with multiple elements (e.g. if the parent uses a `<template>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the slot name.

```
this.$slots.slotName // named slot
this.$slots.default // default slot
```

Example from the [api](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-slots):

```
<blog-post>
  <h1 slot="header">
    About Me
  </h1>

  <p>Here's some page content, which will be included in vm.$slots.default, because it's not inside a named slot.</p>

  <p slot="footer">
    Copyright 2016 Evan You
  </p>

  <p>If I have some content down here, it will also be included in vm.$slots.default.</p>.
</blog-post>

Vue.component('blog-post', {
  render: function (createElement) {
    var header = this.$slots.header
    var body   = this.$slots.default
    var footer = this.$slots.footer
    return createElement('div', [
      createElement('header', header),
      createElement('main', body),
      createElement('footer', footer)
    ])
  }
})
```

Comment: Using this.$slots.slotName returns an array of [Vnode, _rendered: true].

In order to access the element, I find myself having to index in; is there a better way to do this?

Comment: where are you using? its use is basically in render as in the example.

Comment: I'm trying to access the slot's element to get its position in order to position another element relative to that slot.

Comment: `this.$slots.slotName.parentNode`?

Answer (score 0):

As I noted in a comment, you can't count on a slot being filled with a single DOM element; the parent may be using a `<template>` to bundle multiple elements together. In that case, you wouldn't want the position of the first element in the slot.

An alternative approach would be to wrap your slot with a `<div>` element, define a reference to that `<div>`, and then access the reference's position:

```
<div ref="slotWrapper">
    <slot name="slot-name"/>
</div>
```

And then in your code:

```
rect = this.$refs.slotWrapper.getBoundingClientRect();
```